# openjdk 1.7 in eclipse: operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

Tags: eclipse, windows-runtime, java

Eclipse gives me an error:

```
'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
```

I guess this is because it is not using java 1.7. Except that it is. At least openjdk 1.7 (my OS is OpenSuse 12.3).

I switched back from kepler to juno to reduce some lags and try to figure out this bug as well, to no avail so far.

Some things I have tried:
- the default runtime for eclipse is opensdk 1.7 (says so in help, about, installation details)
- project properties, java build -> library. I have manually added the opensdk location.

I would install the oracle version, but there is only 1.6 available from the opensuse repository. I already tried installing the rpm offered by oracle, that didn't put itself in my path and kind of messed everything up, so I removed that again.

It should work with openjdk as well no? Or do you think it has a bug?

ps: junit also was not recognised, so I manually linked to the jar file. Perhaps this is relevant information.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In your project's preferences, you must set the compiler `--source` option to `1.7` and `--target` option to `1.7` also.  There are dedicated option boxes for that.

Right-click on the project.  Choose *Properties*.  Choose *Java Compiler* on the left.  Choose `1.7` for the *Compiler Compliance level*.  If the 2 drop-downs below that aren't `1.7`, uncheck *Use default compliance settings* and set those to `1.7`.

Comment: I reinstalled the oracle jdk. In preferences -> JRE environments I manually added the path to the jde, then in preferences->compiler-> I indeed changed the compliance level (I think that was missing). Thanks so much!

Comment: I am using "PlayHaven Android SDK"... doing so gave me new problem...  Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties. Still wondering how did they compiled it. :O

Comment: This answer worked for me, but I had to perform one additional step: Clean your project BEFORE rebuilding!  This may be a no brainer to most, but I figured it could save some people a few extra minutes of time if they are anything like me.  I tried building before cleaning, and was still getting the above error.

Comment: I'm using v23 of tools - still see this behavior.  For me, I realized it is because new messages are being added to LogCat, EVEN THOUGH they are filtered out.  Whenever adb logcat gets a new message, my scroll area jumps to the bottom, even though it does not display the messages because they are filtered out.

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat have you find solution for that problem?

Comment: what if i am getting this error when updated from using Java 1.7 to Open JDK 11 ?

Answer (score 30):

right click on the error, choose quick fix, and select change JRE to 1.7

Comment: Thank  you, thank you  and thank you. after trying lot of options that ultimately lead me no-man land, this ulitmately saved me, removed hundreds of errors in a one or two clicks.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use below version, use

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

instead of

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 4):

right click on Project - properties - Java Complier - Compiler compliance -set level 1.7

Comment: This doesn't see to add anything new to the existing (accepted) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19382561).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to stick with `java 1.6`, Search and replace <> with empty string.  You'll get compiler warnings but the errors should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with the
 - Compiler Compliance Level
 - Generated .class files compatibility
 - Source compatibility
all already set to 1.7.
I reselected 1.7 on all 3 and then Eclipse detected it, asked to rebuild and built my project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler

select 1.7 and hit okay.

If you are building automatically, it will require a full re-build.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project. Choose Properties. Choose Java Compiler on the left. Choose 1.7 for the Compiler Compliance level. If the 2 drop-downs below that aren't 1.7, uncheck Use default compliance settings and set those to 1.7.