# Eclipse: false error with jdk7

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, java-7

I've been having a problem with eclipse that's been stressing me a lot. Whenever I start a new Java porject, everything goes smoothly and perfect, until I "clean" the project (*Project -> Clean...*) and everything goes to @#~%&...
I keep getting:

- `XYZ cannot be resolved to a type`
- `Multi-catch parameters are not allowed for source level below 1.7`
- `<> operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7`

That's very nice, only that I am importing all required classes and I do have 1.7 since the begginig. It's the only version I've installed. I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382370/openjdk-1-7-in-eclipse-operator-is-not-allowed-for-source-level-below-1-7) and other similar responses for the last few days with no avail.
A solution was to create a new project, copy and paste all packages/clases, which worked for a while, but I added UMLet to the project and again... Removing UMLet plugin did nothing for me.

**BTW**, even with the "errors", my project runs without any problem, therefore I know they're not real. I could keep working, but then, I can't see when a real error arises...
Does anyone got a final solution to get rid of this false errors?

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that I'm working with Kepler.

**EDIT 2:**

Here are screen captures with the requested information.

[image: Java Build Path]

[image: Java Compiler]

Comment: Have you checked the source compliance level of your project or of eclipse in general? Preferences -> Java -> Compiler

Comment: Yep. Everything's on 1.7

Comment: In the *project's* Properties, **Java Build Path** section, **Libraries** tab, what `JRE System Library` is listed there? In the**Java Compiler** section, what is the **JDK Compliance** set to?

Comment: Just edited my question, adding the screen captures showing the requested information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A solution was to create a new project, copy and paste all packages/clases, which worked for a while, but I added UMLet to the project and again...

One possibility is that the UMLet plugin is the cause of your problems.  Try a clean Eclipse install without UMLet.  (The fact that uninstalling the UMLet plugin didn't fix the problem is in no way conclusive.)

Note that UMLet will run as a stand-alone tool.

> BTW, even with the "errors", my project runs without any problem, therefore I know they're not real.

The likely explanation for that is that the compilation errors come from the incremental Java compiler that is built into Eclipse.  A different compiler (i.e. the one from your installed / configured JDK) is used to generate the ".class" files.

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this by setting up correct JRE environment in Eclipse as below.

1. Go to `Project` => `Properties` => `Java Build Path`
2. Click on `Libraries`
3. Select `JRE System Library`
4. Click on Edit button at right hand side
5. Set `Execution Environment` to `Jave SE-1.7(jre7)`
6. Clean project or refresh project.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-catch parameters are not allowed for source level below 1.7

not a solution, to this issue, but if you want to have two exceptions you can code it like this:

```
try {
    // code here
} catch {
    // code here
} catch {
    // code here
}
```

it worked for me, instead of having catch `(exception1 | exception2 e)`