# Unable to import the latest Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, import, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to import facebook-android-sdk-4.1.2 into my workspace but it is showing number of errors. I don't know where the problem is.

[image: Import error]

Comment: this can help you, follow the steps with your sdk : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961828/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-studio`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19382561/4801418

or try "right click on the error, choose quick fix, and select change JRE to 1.7"