# How to fix '<>'operator is not allowed for source level 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using JDK 1.8.0. When I import the code into Eclipse I am getting the error:

> '<>'operator is not allowed for source level 1.7

Example:

```
List<String[]> errors = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am using **Eclipse Kepler**.

Comment: Show us an example of the code with this error.

Comment: List<String[]> errors = new ArrayList<>();for such declarations.

Comment: Are you sure the error message is not "'<>' operator is not allowed for source level **below** 1.7"?

Comment: yeah i am sure about that.

Comment: Maven?  You must set the compiler level in pom.xml

Comment: Will you help me how to declare dat in pom file?? and where in pom?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [openjdk 1.7 in eclipse: operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382370/openjdk-1-7-in-eclipse-operator-is-not-allowed-for-source-level-below-1-7)

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes I have seen Eclipse become confused about the Java target version, and throw incorrect messages (even if the project is set up correctly to support Java 7). The easiest way to fix it is to change the target version, then change it back to the expected target version.

This version can be checked by opening the Project properties dialog (right click on the project, and select `Properties`), and check the settings on two tabs:

1. `Java Compiler` tab: Check whether there are any specific settings such as always use a JDK version, etc. By default, all settings here are set to "Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.x' on the 'Java build path'." (where x is a Java version). If a specific Java version (pre-Java 7) is selected here, then select the one you are targeting, and you should be done. If the previously mentioned checkbox is set, then follow to step 2.
2. `Java build path` tab: Go to libraries, and edit the JRE system library accordingly.

Again, if both settings seem correct, change the latter, rebuild your project (e.g. close your dialog), then change it back and rebuild.

Remarks: if you are using a Maven/Gradle project, it is possible that you should edit these settings in the Maven/Gradle configuration.

Answer (score 10):

It needs to update the value of "Compiler compliance level" to 1.7 or higher in eclipse. Steps are as below:

1. Open project in eclipse
2. Right click on Project and go to Properties
3. In Properties panel: click "Java Compiler" at the left and update the value of "Compiler compliance level" to 1.7 or higher from the drop down.
4. Click Apply and OK button
   [image]

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your pom.xml, below `<project>`.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Most likely it's the default Eclipse Maven configuration that set your project's JDK version to 1.5 - God knows why. This will set it to 1.8 instead.

Comment: for me this is not enougth, also need rigth click on project and choose Maven->update project

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Eclipse Mars or latest version Neon :

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: Please update your answer and explain *why* OP should do that.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting   8 in the  section of the pom (maven) helped in my case.

Comment: "<java.version>8</java.version>" in the "<properties>"  section

Answer (score -2):

Try the followings:

```
List<String[]> errors = new ArrayList();
```

OR,

```
List<String[]> errors = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Or, change your project Compiler compliance level to 1.7 or higher in Eclipse.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Incorrect number of arguments for type ArrayList<E>; it cannot be parameterized with 
  arguments <>
 - '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

Comment: can you post your imports?

Comment: I am using kepler.In dropdown i am able to see upto 1.7 only

Comment: Set it to 1.7 and you'll be fine.

Comment: ya i did that.But den too the same issue.

Comment: Did you clean the project after changing the compliance level?

Comment: Please visit the following link for setting "Compiler compliance level" in Eclipse:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217983/how-to-fix-operator-is-not-allowed-for-source-level-1-7/51895133#51895133

Comment: How to change the project Compiler compliance level to 1.7 or higher in Eclipse?